# "find" cannot perform conditional depth search

Tags: bash, filesystems, find

tried to have "find" to perform conditional depth search,
if the found is in current dir. and the found is a file then do explain its output with verbal, else then do output just like normally

```
$ find ~+ -maxdepth 1 \( -type f -printf 'File: %p\n' -o  -printf '%p\n' \) -o -mindepth 2 -printf '%p\n'

find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option argument (, but options are not positional (-mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it)..
```

Why is it failed and How to solve such the demanded condition ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-maxdepth`/`-mindepth` (a non-standard GNU extension, though now supported by quite a few other `find` implementations) are not *condition* predicates, they're global flags that affect the way `find` descends into directories.

[It's possible to implement the effect of `-maxdepth` standardly with a combination of `-path` and `-prune`](/a/330372).

[FreeBSD's `find`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) has `-depth n/-n/+` to match files at depth `n` / < `n` / > `n`, so on FreeBSD or derivatives (macOS, DragonFly BSD...), it would just be:

```
find ~+ -depth 1 -type f -exec printf 'File: %s' {} ';' -o -print
```

here using `-exec printf` in place of the GNU-specific `-printf`.

Technically, `printf` could fail which would trigger `-print`. Using `-exec ... {} +` instead of `-exec ... {} ';'` would address that but affect the order of display. Or it could be changed to:

```
find ~+ -depth 1 -type f '(' -exec printf 'File: %s' {} ';' -o -true ')' -o -print
```

Or:

```
find ~+ '(' ! -depth 1 -o ! -type f ')' -print -o -exec printf 'File: %s' {} ';'
```

Standardly, `-path` can be used instead (though not as straightforwardly).

```
LC_ALL=C find ~+/. -path '*/./*/*' -print -o \
  -type f -printf 'File: %p\n' -o -print
```

Or to limit the depth to 2 (as in an earlier version of my answer where I thought your `-mindepth 2` was `-maxdepth 2`)

```
LC_ALL=C find ~+/. -path '*/./*/*' -prune -print -o \
  -type f -printf 'File: %p\n' -o -print
```

(still not standard as `-printf` is GNU specific).

We append `/.` to the path (which is otherwise guaranteed not to occur in `$PWD`/`~+`), to mark the depth 0 point for `find`'s `-path`.

You can't use `-path "$PWD/*/*"` instead (as in [your suggested edit](/review/suggested-edits/354022)) as that wouldn't work properly for values of `$PWD` that contain wildcard characters or backslashes (since `-path` considers its argument as a wildcard pattern).

Compare:

```
$ mkdir -p '[1]/2/3/4'
$ touch '[1]/2/3/4/file'
$ cd '[1]'
$ LC_ALL=C find ~+ -path "$PWD/*/*" -print -o -type f -printf 'File: %p\n' -o -print
/tmp/[1]
/tmp/[1]/2
/tmp/[1]/2/3
/tmp/[1]/2/3/4
File: /tmp/[1]/2/3/4/file
$ LC_ALL=C find ~+/. -path '*/./*/*' -print -o -type f -printf 'File: %p\n' -o -print
/tmp/[1]/.
/tmp/[1]/./2
/tmp/[1]/./2/3
/tmp/[1]/./2/3/4
/tmp/[1]/./2/3/4/file
```

Another approach is to append `//`, though that's less portable as some `find` implementations remove those excess trailing `/`s.

You can pipe to `sed 's:/\./:/:'` to remove those `/./`s on output.

`LC_ALL=C` is needed with GNU `find` where `*` fails to match path components that contain sequence of bytes not forming valid characters.

---

While GNU `find` has no predicate to explicitly match on the depth of files, its `-printf` predicate can *print* that depth. So here, you could add that `File:`  prefix to regular files at depth 1 with some post-processing:

```
find . -printf '%d%y,%p\0' | # print depth, type and path
  sed -z 's/^1f,/&File: /' | # add "File: " prefix for regulars at depth 1  
  cut -zd, -f2-            | # remove the depth and type
  tr '\0' '\n'               # NL delimited for user consumption
```

Comment: @nonoch, I rejected the edit as the argument of `-path` is taken as a pattern, so `-path "$PWD/*/*"` wouldn't work with arbitrary values of `$PWD` (those containing wildcards or backslashes specifically).

Comment: @nonoch, I just realised you had `-mindepth 2` and not `-maxdepth 2` though, so I'll need to change that.

Comment: @nonoch, as I said, `-path "$PWD/*/*"` wouldn't work with arbitrary values of `$PWD`. See comment above and my latest edit that should also fix my earlier misreading of your question.

Comment: @nonoch, see example in my latest edit.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas `-depth` is a POSIX standard `find` primary that inverts the order of the output. It causes the directory content to be printed before the directory. This is not related to`-mindepth` at all. Also note that `libfind` implements `-mindepth` and `-maxdelth` as normal primaries that always yield in TRUE.

Comment: @schily, I'm not talking of the `-depth` alone standard predicate here, but of the unrelated [FreeBSD `find`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=find&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html)'s `-depth n` extension. The behaviour for `find . -depth 1` is unspecified by POSIX. By *GNU extension*, I meant it was of GNU *origin*. `-mindepth`/`-maxdepth` is now supported by a few  other implementations.

Comment: GNU progams are frequently implementing badly designed interfaces (see the useless `-amin` primary in `gfind` compared to the enhanced `-atime` in `libfind` (see http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/sfind.1.html) and FreeBSD, but the hard to parse `-depth` extension from FreeBSD is an unhappy decision. `gfind`s claim `-mindepth` to be an option is nonsense, since then it would need to appear before file type arguments. BTW: Even FreeBSD supports `-mindepth`, so it makes no sense to mention the FreeBSD mistake with `-depth xxx`.

Comment: @schily, `-mindepth`/`-maxdepth` and `-depth` don't do the same thing. `-mindepth`/`-maxdepth` are global flags (like you say not options in that they are not processed like the `-L`, `-H`... ones) which affect the traversal and would be of no use in this Q&A. `-depth n` is a condition predicate that returns true if the file is at depth n but otherwise doesn't affect `find`'s traversal of the directory tree (as long as you don't use `-prune` based on its result).

Comment: @schily About GNU find and options, note that it's all about terminology. `find` initially didn't have any option in the `getopt()` sense of the term. GNU find classifies its predicates as *Options*, *Test* or *Action* ones and has done so since long before POSIX introduced `getopt()`-style options for it (one of which, `-L`, duplicates the `-follow` *option* predicate). I used *flag* in my answer to avoid the possible confusion.

Comment: I still see no benefit from the FreeBSd enhancement and  BTW: Whom do you like to explain the getopt() thing?

Comment: @schily, `-depth n` matches at depth n. That's the predicate that answers exactly the OP's question. See edit where  I make that more explicit. Without it, you have to use those convoluted approaches with `-path` and where you need to fix the locale to C with all the implications it has. That's the whole point of my answer.